# Book (possibly part of a series) about a martial arts school, included a section with a punch thrown with a butterfly in the hand

Tags: identification-request

I read this as a paperback in the mid 1990s in English, probably between 200 and 300 pages. My brain is associating the book with various TSR series I read at the time, although that might just be a matter of a similar paperback form factor. The protagonist is studying at a martial arts school (like the Shaolin temples?), I think on a mountain. The martial arts felt very Chinese-inspired, maybe some form of *wu shu*. The bit that's stuck with me over the decades was a section where the teacher was trying to teach the students to not tightly ball their hand up during their strikes, and demonstrated by capturing a butterfly in his hand, and proceeding to punch through a solid wooden fence, then releasing the butterfly unharmed, leading that fence post to be replaced with one with a carving of a butterfly to memorialize the teaching.

I don't remember any magic or chi being mentioned, so this might have been relatively grounded rather than a fantasy book, although I don't think it was supposed to be historically accurate.

Just to rule out a common search result I've encountered trying to research this, I am certain that it is not part of R.A. Salvatore's *Cleric Quintet* and its monk, Danica.